# Construct object from "dumb" base class

Tags: c++, constructor

I created a "smart variant" of a standard structure - there's the `struct canmsg` provided by the system, data of that type is read from a can device, and I frequently handle such frames.

Now, for easier handling them I created a child class: `class TCanFrame : public canmsg`. It doesn't have any extra properties, but it has a bunch of methods - a friendly constructor for creating the frames from scratch, commands and data, getters and setters that read and set different properties "abstraction layer above" (e.g. channel subaddresses encoded in data).

What is the best method of constructing an object of the type TCanFrame from an instance of `struct canmsg_t`? Can I just do a memcpy from `&source` to `this`? Or would I need to copy it field-by-field? Or some other trick to have a neat TCanFrame instance created out of "dumb" `canmsg` Or maybe can I make the copy constructor to accept the parent class?

Comment: Even if it is correct and could probably work, I don't think memcopying it would be so safe... a copy field by field is for me the proper way to do it, by the way, i'm not so fan to construct a class from a struct/class wich isn't yours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use default copy constructor provided by the compiler:

```
TCanFrame(const canmsg& msg) : canmsg(msg) {}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't add any data members, and don't need to access any protected members of `canmsg`, I think you shouldn't create a derived class. Instead, you can add free functions to do the extra functionality into the namespace where `canmsg` is defined, and then use them with normal `canmsg` objects. You can read more about a class's "non-member interface" and why it's a good thing in e.g. these articles by [Scott Meyers](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) and [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm).

Also note that if you do create a derived class and `canmsg` doesn't have a virtual destructor, you can easily run into undefined behaviour by calling `delete` on a `canmsg*` which actually points to a `TCanFrame` object.

Comment: 'Breaking if something changes' as argued in these articles is not my concern here - I'm operating on OS-provided structures that are unlikely to change before their underlying technology vanishes into obscurity. OTOH, they neglect readability. `CanFrame::Length(msg)` is far less readable than `msg.Length()`.

Comment: @SF. The point is that you don't have to do `CanFrame::Length(msg)`, you can just do `Length(msg)` and the appropriate `Length` will be found by [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). I don't find this any less readable, and it has benefits: it will work with all `canmsg` objects, not just your own wrappers, and you save yourself the data duplication. As an example, `static_pointer_cast` et al. are also functions in namespace `std` and not members of `std::shared_ptr`.